how to handle native context date picker in a mobile automation (webview in chrome browser)
I am using Chrome dev tool to inspect web mobile elements. But I can’t inspect the calendar using the chrome dev tool (chrome://inspect/#devices). It doesn’t show up on the calendar. I want to click ‘Set’ button on the calendar. but unable to find the locator for that. Is there a way to find the locator on the calendar?

My framework is cross platform automation and trying to automate web app now. Can you please help me how to find the locator for ‘Set’ on the calendar. I must click on ‘Set’ in order to get ‘Continue’ button enabled. Enter date using javascript executor doesn;t enale continue button.
Tried solution from this link
How to inspect calendar elements - Chrome /android?
But for me "The method getContextHandles() is undefined for the type RemoteWebDriver" error is thrown.

